# Enable/Disable Kendo DropDownList Razor with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use angularJs (version 1.3.0) with kendo-asp.net.mvc (version 2015.1.429).

I want to know if is possible enable/disable Kendo Razor helper DropDownList using AngularJs.

Code Example (i want disabled kendo dropdownlist "DdlTest" if i choose the first element "Black" with value "1" from dropdownlist "color") :

**.cshtml Page**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <h4>Cap Color</h4>
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("color")
            .HtmlAttributes(new
            {
                ng_model="selectedField",
                ng_change="changeField(kendoEvent)"
            })
            .DataTextField("Text")
            .DataValueField("Value")
            .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
                new SelectListItem() {
                    Text = "Black",
                    Value = "1"
                },
                new SelectListItem() {
                    Text = "Orange",
                    Value = "2"
                }
            })
        )

        <h4 style="margin-top: 2em;">Cap Size</h4>
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("DdlTest")
            .BindTo(new List<string>() {
                "S - 6 3/4\"",
                "M - 7 1/4\"",
                "L - 7 1/8\"",
                "XL - 7 5/8\""
            })
        )
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is AngularJs Code**

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["kendo.directives"]);

    app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {
        $scope.selectedField = "0";
        $scope.changeField = function(e) {
            switch ($scope.selectedField) {
                case '1':
                    $scope.DdlTest.enable(false);
                    break;

                default:
                    $scope.DdlTest.enable(true);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

When i change the value of dropdownlist i receive:

> Error: $scope.DdlTest is undefined

I tried to insert in the HtmlAttributes of dropdownlist "DdlTest" the value:

```
kendo_drop_down_list = "DdlTest"
```

but it doesn't work on IE and Firefox, it seems work only on chrome.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible use angularJs with kendo mvc components in Razor?
If is possible, how i can enable/disable a kendo dropdownlist?

Comment: Kendo says the server wrappers are [not supported](http://www.telerik.com/forums/ui-for-asp-net-mvc-with-angularjs).

Comment: thanks @SteveGreene. I tried to test because in a webapplication i have a area that is a SinglePage Application developed in kendo ui asp.net mvc and JQuery, but it's difficoult to maintain. I feared that if i want to use angularJs i will have to use simple [kendo-ui with angularJs integration](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction)

Comment: I'm making a similar transition: using angular + kendo + web api. There is definitely a learning curve (especially setting up the datasources), but I like the results so far.